# pgfplots stacked bar chart - layout of labels - changing colors while having labels - formatting of labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This is a follow up question to my first steps with pgf. The chart is now somehow how I want it to be, but it doesn't look perfect yet.
I tried to figure it out with the manual, but well...

- Is it possible to include a line break in the labels, that are to long (maybe automatic)?
- Is formatting of the text possible? When I used textbf, I got errors
- How to change the colour of each bar. The only solution I found, needs to remove the text labels

**Thanks** all you tikz experts in advance :)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width=0.7\textwidth,
    height=0.7\textwidth,
    bar width=.5\textwidth,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0,
    ylabel={Spannung in V},
    symbolic x coords={tool1},
    xtick=data,
    xtick style={draw=none},
    xticklabel=\empty,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=70,
    ]
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,20) [thisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) [thisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,12) [thisisalongword with anotherthisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,16) [thisisalongword with anotherthisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,2) [thisisalongword with anotherthisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) [andagain thisisalongerword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,2) [thisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,10) [andagain thisisalongerword]};         
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: got an error, when compiled.

Comment: @SamjithDasan It works for me! (See also:https://www.overleaf.com/read/nsbkzsbkrwgg)

Comment: Oh! something went wrong from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `every node near coord/.style={text width=3 cm,},` you can set the width of a text node.
- Add `fill=color` to `\addplot` such as: `\addplot+[ybar, fill=red] plot....` to change the color.
- You can make the font bold via `every node near coord/.style={font=\bfseries},`

You can also change much more via `every node near coord/.style`. Such as if you don't like that the text is aligned on the left, but you want it centered, then add `align=center`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width=0.7\textwidth,
    height=0.7\textwidth,
    bar width=.5\textwidth,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0,
    ylabel={Spannung in V},
    symbolic x coords={tool1},
    xtick=data,
    xtick style={draw=none},
    xticklabel=\empty,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=70,
    every node near coord/.style={text width=3 cm, font=\bfseries, align=center},
    ]
    \addplot+[ybar, fill=red] plot coordinates {(tool1,20) [thisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar, fill=blue] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) [thisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,12) [thisisalongword with anotherthisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,16) [thisisalongword with anotherthisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,2) [thisisalongword with anotherthisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) [andagain thisisalongerword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,2) [thisisalongword]};
    \addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,10) [andagain thisisalongerword]};         
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I thing \bfseries should be used insetad of \bf. Otherwise Latex throws errors (with Komascript)

Comment: I tried to put the fill comand in the wrong bracket... I guess it will need some time, till I get used to tikz and pgf

Comment: @Marcel I changed it. I looked it up and \bf is depreciated an use is discouraged. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I have to thank you. (I changed it in your MWE as well) If someone in the future finds this topic: font=\small\bfseries works as well. And with draw=none next to the fill command, the colourful borders are eliminated :)